# Why is findByIdAndUpdate() not updating an _id's information? (using $set)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a beginner in MongoDB and have been following a tutorial from one year ago. I send a PUT request with the following json:

```json
{   
    "username": "NoMore"
}
```

Then I use findByIdAndUpdate() with the _id being pulled from the url's :id params. The function is async, but await is used on the update function. Despite the code seeming to have worked one year ago, I can not find any updated information regarding this online.

My entire function is as follows:

```js
router.put('/:id', verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.password) {
        req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            req.body.password, 
            process.env.PASS_SEC
        ).toString();
    }
    
    try {
        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id, 
            {
                $set: req.body,
            }, 
            { new: true },
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})
```

I have tried setting the _id manually as a string, but the code still went to an error 500. I also preset the req.body which did not change the result.

I am expecting for the user's username to become the username sent in the PUT request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't import the model (User) so there was no connection to MongoDB.

I put the following code at the top:

```js
const User = require('../models/User');
```

Now it works fine.